# Stored Procedures and Variables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I made a stored procedure which has the following `parameter`: `@UserName`

Would that mean, in the ASP.NET, I would have to do the following code to update the value of `username`?

```
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
```

Or would this *make* a new parameter? If this just makes a new `parameter`, how can I just set the `Parameter`'s value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would create a new parameter.  Parameters is a collection that you can access by name, so you can do something like this to update an existing param:

`dbCommand.Parameters["@UserName"] = userName;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like `dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);` or

```
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
dbCommand.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = userName;
```

Comment: What do each of those statements do?

Comment: The first one adds the parameter with an initial value. The second pair of lines adds the parameter, then edits the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar) 
    { Value = userName });
```

Comment: Adds a parameter to the collection with a value. I may have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation.  Here are a few common cases:

If you're using a datasource in your mark-up, then just use the wizard to configure your datasource, and it will discover your parameter automatically.  Then you can see how it adds your parameter to your datasource's mark-up.

If you're using a datasource + code-behind, you can **add parameters** as you have in your post.  As long as you don't ALSO have the parameter in your datasource mark-up, this will be fine.

If you're using a datasource + code-behind, you can **assign values to parameters it already has** like this: `.Parameters["@UserName"].defaultvalue = "some value"`

If you're NOT using a datasource, and doing everything in code-behind, then you can do this: `.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", "some value, some text value of a control, etc.")`